# How to create the strings sequence into specified line in edited text?

Tags: vim

Here is the initial text.

```
test1
test2
```

Only two lines in the text.

I want to insert strings sequence into from 5th line into 16th line.
I have tried it with below codes.

```
for i in range(1,12)  
    echo ".item".i.","
endfor
```

1.the initial text.
[image]
2.to enter into command mode and input the codes

[image]

Two problems to be solved.
1.echo command output the first string `.item1` before endfor.

```
for i in range(1,12)  
    echo ".item".i.","
```

2.How create the strings sequence into specified line:from 5th till 16th in edited text with vimscript?

The desired result is as below.

[image]

Almost done！
What i get is as below with the command  `:pu! =map(range(1,12), 'printf(''item%1d'', v:val)')`.

Both of them can't work.

```
:5pu! =map(range(1,12), 'printf(''item%1d'', v:val)')
:5,16pu! =map(range(1,12), 'printf(''item%1d'', v:val)')
```

[image]

The last issue for my desired format is when the cursor is on the 3th line ,how to create the desired output?

Comment: Do you mean something like this `pu! =map(range(1,16), 'printf(''item%1d'', v:val)')`? If not, you should show the desired output. I'm having trouble determining what it is you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to insert the missing lines, without inserting unrequired empty lines (-> `append()` + `repeat([''], nb)` + possible negative `nb`)

```
:let lin = 5 - 1
:call append('$', repeat([''], lin-line('$')))
```

Then, in order to insert what you're looking for (no need for `printf()` if you don't want to format the numbers)

```
:call append(lin, map(range(1,12), '"item".v:val'))
```

PS: I'd rather avoid `:put` when I can as it's kind of difficult to use with complex expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in a Unix based operating system, you have a `seq` command.
So you can do:

```
$ seq -f 'Item %.0f' 20
Item 1
Item 2
...
Item 20
```

Inside `vim` you can try the **reading from external command** approach:

```
:r! seq -f 'Item \%.0f' 20
```